# Button not submitting on enter

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an search form and I have to click on the button to submit the search. What I want is it to search when hitting enter, but it does not work any suggestions.

```
     <button class="btn btn-default" style="height:34px" type="submit" onclick="Search();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

Here's my form

```
    <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">   
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTrm, new { @class="form-control",id="Searchterm",placeholder="Search for Drug, Disease or Sponsor"})  

            <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-default" style="height:34px" type="button" onclick="Search();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>

            </span>
```

Comment: Is it inside form tag ?

Comment: change type="submit" for type="button" and test it

Comment: can you show your form?

Comment: no i have not used form tag. is that why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enter to submit a form, you must have a form and a form control must have focus when enter is pressed (except for textarea elements, where enter will insert a carriage return). You must move the button's click handler to the form's submit handler (otherwise it won't get called).

Button elements in a form are submit buttons by default.

e.g.

```js
function search(form) {
  alert('You are searching on: ' + form.searchText.value);
  // do stuff 
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="search(this)">
  Search text: <input name="searchText">
  <button>Do search</button>
</form>
```